# Кодировка на HTTP сервере Apache @ ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, apache2

Добрый день

На VPS Ubuntu сервере, развернуто приложение (oracle-XE + PHP), под управлением apache2. PHP взаимодействует с БД через oci8.

Все значения, которые возвращают селекты из БД на страницу, возвращаются в виде "?????????". Т.е., вся кириллица нечитаема. При этом, статичный текст на странице отражается корректно.

При этом, на другом VPS сервере все работает отлично. Явно, где то есть разница в конфигах, но пока что я не нашел где.

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Так же во всех php скриптах, которые возвращают значения, есть строка:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Так же в apache2.conf пробовал добавлять

```
AddDefaultCharset Utf-8
```

не помогло.

.bashrc

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
LANG=en_US.C
```

SELECT напрямую из БД возвращает кириллицу корректно

Comment: вопросы любит оракл возвращать когда кодировку не понимает. apache выдывал бы абракадабру а не вопросы. Мои перловые скрипты перед коннектом к базе всегда явно выставляют переменную окружения `NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN.AL32UTF8`. php вряд ли будет выполнять .bashrc. возможно так же стоит прямо в коде указать через putenv или как то еще передать драйверу.

Comment: У меня была рекоммендация: В конфигурационном файле необходимо прописать установку переменных окружения базы данных:
SetEnv NLS_LANG AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251                                     Вопрос: где прописывать эту строчку? Я пробовал в php.ini, не помогло

Comment: SetEnv - это директива apache. В конфиге апача или .htacess. Только немного странно выглядит задавать тут 1251, а в кодировке страниц апача utf8 ... И AMERICAN_CIS, пробелов быть не должно

Comment: Да, и напишите если получится, в ответ тогда переделаю.

Comment: Пока что ничего не получилось, я сравнивал настройки двух серверов (на первом работает, на втором - нет) - различия не нашел. Честно говоря, не пойму, где мне прописывать "SetEnv ...". Как то везде (например, тут: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm) поверхностно описано. В php коде точно менять ничего не стоит, потому что код на двух серверах одинаковый. По моему, это явно настраивается в apache2 или php, только где и что настраивать я пока не понял :(

Comment: А где вы писали `AddDefaultCharset Utf-8` вот там же попробуйте, прямо следующей строкой. Еще это может быть глобально на сервере, где нибудь в /etc/profile вообще поищите упоминания NLS_LANG во всем /etc: `grep -r NLS_LANG /etc`

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Пробовал ставить следующие варианты:         # SetEnv NLS_LANG AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
# SetEnv NLS_LANG AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8                                но после перезапуска апача, ничего не изменяется. При этом, AddDefaultCharset и AddCharset явно давали эффект, когда я с ними эксперементировал, кодировка изменялась. Пока что безуспешно

Comment: для начала сделайте какой нибудь запрос из sqllpus и посмотрите что там с кодировкой. кстати, V$NLS_PARAMETERS на серверах совпадают ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36664/discussion-between-vyacheslav-groshenkov-and-mike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для настройки кодировки для клиента оракла должны быть правильно выставлены переменные окружения `NLS_LANG`, `ORACLE_HOME` и возможно `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Как было выяснено после различных экспериментов, oci8 php ни в какую не хотел брать переменные окружения, заданные в конфиге apache. Он их принял после того, как они были добавлены в виде строк `export NLS_LANG=....` в файл envvars, загружаемый при старте apache. Для debian он находится в `/etc/apache2/envvars`, для gentoo в `/etc/conf.d/apache2`. В других дистрибутивах его упоминание можно найти в `/etc/init.d/apache2` или добавить требуемые строки непосредственно в него.